# How to use logisticinfotech/ionic4-datepicker in a reactive form in Ionic 4/Angular7?

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I'm new to Ionic and Angular. I have a reactive form (ReactiveFormsModule) with a date field. I'm trying to use the ionic4-datepicker component created as a replacement to the ionic-datetime element. After reading their blog (https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/ionic4-datepicker-component/), I still have trouble getting and setting a selected date to the date field. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Updated 9/17/2019:**

Not sure what happened, but the datepicker works after I created the form again from scratch and cleared my browser cache. I have not figured out how to trigger the function call to myFunction(). It's not a big deal since I don't to need perform any validation or business logic, but would be nice to know.

**Here are the working codes. Enjoy.**

**create-form.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-form',
    templateUrl: './create-form.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-form.page.scss'],
})
export class CreateFormPage implements OnInit {

    submitted = false;
    createForm: FormGroup;

    datePickerObjDefaultSettings: any = {}

    datePickerObjCustomSettings: any = {
        inputDate: new Date(),
        fromDate: null,
        toDate: null,
        showTodayButton: true,
        closeOnSelect: true,
        disableWeekDays: [0],
        mondayFirst: true,
        setLabel: 'Set',
        todayLabel: 'Today',
        closeLabel: 'Close',
        disabledDates: [],
        titleLabel: 'Select a Date',
        monthsList: ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        weeksList: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
        dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        clearButton: true,
        momentLocale: 'en-US',
        yearInAscending: true,
        btnCloseSetInReverse: true,
        btnProperties: {
            expand: 'block',
            fill: '',
            size: '',
            disabled: '',
            strong: '',
            color: ''
        },
        highlightedDates: []
    };

    validation_messages = {
        'name': [
            { type: 'required', message: 'Name is required.' },
            { type: 'minlength', message: 'Name must be at least 3 characters long.' },
            { type: 'maxlength', message: 'Name cannot be more than 100 characters long.' },
        ]
    }

    constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
            fromDate: [''],
            toDate: [''],
        });
    }


    onSubmit(value: any): void {
        this.submitted = true;

        if (this.createForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    }

    onReset() {
        this.submitted = false;
        this.createForm.reset();
    }

    // Either there is a typo in the third-party documentation or bug in the plugin.
    // This function is NOT invoked.
    myFunction() {
        console.log("===> myFunction: ");
    }

}
```

**create-form.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <form [formGroup]="createForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(createForm.value)">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.name">
                <div class="error-message"
                    *ngIf="createForm.get('name').hasError(validation.type) && (createForm.get('name').dirty || createForm.get('name').touched)">
                    <ion-icon name="information-circle-outline"></ion-icon> {{ validation.message }}
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">From Date</ion-label>
            <ion-input readonly formControlName="fromDate" [liIonic4Datepicker]="datePickerObjDefaultSettings" (ionchange)="myFunction()"></ion-input>
            <!-- <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" min="2017-01-01"></ion-datetime> -->
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">To Date</ion-label>
            <ion-input readonly formControlName="toDate" [liIonic4Datepicker]="datePickerObjCustomSettings" (ionchange)="myFunction()"></ion-input>
            <!-- <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" min="2017-01-01"></ion-datetime> -->
        </ion-item>

        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-button expand="block" size="medium" type="submit" [disabled]="!createForm.valid">Create</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-button expand="block" size="medium" type="reset" (click)="onReset()">Reset</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </form>

</ion-content>
```

**create-form.scss**

```
.error-message {
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using also [(ngModel)] inside the ion-input?

Comment: I tried to used the two-way data binding with [(ngModel)] in a reactive form, but got this error:  `ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's normal that liIonic4Datepicker has its own type of date. If you want to set default date into datepicker, you need to write util function that transform UTC date to datepicker format date. Then patch result into form (in OnInit method). Like that:

```
    convertDate(UTCdate: Date) {
     return .....
    }

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.patch({myDate: convertDate('YOUR_DATE')})
  // or 
  this.myForm.controls.myDate.setValue(convertDate('YOUR_DATE'))
}
```

If you want submit form, you should do same things to convert datepicker date into normal date.

```
submitForm {
 const { myDate } = this.myForm.value;
 convertedDate = convertToUTC(myDate);
 this.api.submit(convertedDate)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was able to fix my issue.  I have not checked the liIonic4Datepicker date type, but have a solution for it when it comes to date conversion.